# What is the number above rrd-h on copywrite page

Tags: publishing

What does the number under the library of congress control number and above rrd-h?  The number is 31

Comment: Are you talking about the printer's key? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer%27s_key It gives the year of the current reprint, sometimes also the number of reprints. But since we know nothing about the book in question, it could be anything. So please provide an image of the copyright page or type it below your question. Use four spades at the beginning of each line.

Comment: "RRD (H)" means the book was printed by R.R. Donnelley http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RR_Donnelley The lowest number to the left of "RRD (H)" is the year the book was printed, the lowest number to the right is the number of this reprint. E.g. "96 RRD (H) 20 19 18 17 16 15" means that this is the 15th reprint, which was printed in 1996. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the copyright pages of several books, there is no standard for placement of library of congress numbers that is broadly applied. In several cases books by the same publisher did not use the same layout. Therefore with confidence I can not only say 'I don't know,' but I can also say 'No one other than god and the publisher can know.'

Comment: Well, and someone who has this particular book in his hand. Or someone who has divined the mysteries of the universe to the extent that he can discern what the layout of the copyright page of any book would be just by knowing the LCCN. :-)